# SQL Syntax Questions

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I got a table name `users` with a field name `country` and a field name `id`

I also got a table name `Players` with a field name `gameID`  (also it got an `user_id` for id the user id on `users` )

I would like to make an `UPDATE` that change at field `gameID` from the table `Players` the `STEAMID_0xxxx` for `STEAMID_1xxxxx` when the `country` from table `users is = uk`

I trying something like this:

```
UPDATE Players 
set steamid=steam_1 
WHERE steamid=steamid_0 AND country = ( SELECT country 
                                        from users 
                                        where country=pt )
```

So my first doubts, how to change just a part of the word (ex: `steam_0:1:2345 to steam_1:1:2345`) it is `Steam_0* ?` also, how do I select the country? my theory looks stupid :|

I know that's wrong, maybe you can point me in right direction

Thank you in advance

Comment: it's better to post your schema ( as well as some sample data ) here

Answer (score 1):

You will need to `JOIN` against `users` to get the country:

To swap `steam_0` for `steam_1`, you can use the `REPLACE()` string function:

```
UPDATE 
  Players
  JOIN users ON Players.user_id = users.id
SET
  /* REPLACE() the beginnging steamid_0 with steamid_1 */
  steamid = REPLACE(steamid, 'steamid_0:', 'steamid_1:')
WHERE
  /* The whole subquery can then be replaced with this: */
  users.country = 'pt'
  /* Not strictly necessary... */
  AND LEFT(steamid, 10) = 'steamid_0:'
```

Comment: the country is on the "users" table not on the "Players" so I think i need to do somekind of select?

Comment: @user676032 See update. I added a `JOIN` against `users` to take care of that.

Comment: and if the "users" table is on a differnt database? The players table is on one database, and users table is on a differnt one?

Comment: @user676032 If they are on different databases, you just need to be sure that the established connection can read both of them and reference the db as well, as in `UPDATE db1.Players JOIN db2.users ON db1.Players.user_id = db2.users.id`